# VS2019 Adding automatically HideSelection

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a VS2015 WINFORM VB.NET project on VS2019, after i've changed the image of a ImageView, VS2019 automatically added to all panels and lbls the `Me.lstSCO.HideSelection = False` and that broked lot of code and i had manually change it back to true or by removing it.

Is VisualStudio 2019 adding automatically HideSelection set to False?

If so how could i prevent it?

Comment: That's the default behavior in .Net 4.8 (+) and .Net Core, related to the new Accessibility features enabled by default. It's also documented, in [ListView.HideSelection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection). You can opt out: see [What's new in accessibility in the .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#accessibility-switches). If that's a good idea, it's up to you to decide. This also can have consequences. You may just *update* your understanding of the new default  behavior.

Comment: @Jimi theproject actually is in Framework 3.5 so i don't think that it's the case...

Comment: This is the default behavior when accessibility features are activated. If you have .Net 4.7.1+ installed, at least one of the enhanced feature is enabled. Visual Studio does make use the accessibility features behavior after a newer version of the Framework is installed in the machine. See [System.Windows.Forms.ListView HideSelection Default Value Incorrect](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-early-access/issues/45). There *might be* an `AppContext` switch (to create) to add to the Registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework`, but it affects all applications...